# Issues writing doubles to files, writing nothing

Tags: java

I seem to be missing something when it comes to writing doubles to text files, when I check the file, just blank space is present. When I read from the file and print with System.out.println(); it just prints nothing... What's going wrong here? Do I need to do some converting?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ReadCalcAveragePrint  {

    double firstNum;
    double secondNum;
    double average;

    public void readFile() {

        try {
            File f = new File("numbers.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String one = br.readLine();
            String two = br.readLine();
            firstNum = Double.parseDouble(one);
            secondNum = Double.parseDouble(two);

            average = (firstNum + secondNum) / 2;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, average, "title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    public void writeFile() {
        try {
            File f = new File("result.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
            dos.writeDouble(average);
            dos.flush();
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("Printed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }

    public void readResult() {

        try {
            File f = new File("result.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String one = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(one);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ReadCalcAveragePrint().readFile();
        new ReadCalcAveragePrint().writeFile();
        new ReadCalcAveragePrint().readResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `main` you are creating 3 different objects, only the first is going to contain the numbers you read from the file.

You should just create and reuse one object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReadCalcAveragePrint obj = new ReadCalcAveragePrint();
    obj.readFile();
    obj.writeFile();
    obj.readResult();
}
```

Also you are writing the result file using `DataOutputStream` which is meant to write the data in binary form. If you just want to save the result as text you should use `FileWriter` instead:

```
File f = new File("result.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
fw.write(String.valueOf(average));
fw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

see the javadoc of writeDouble:

> Converts the double argument to a long using the doubleToLongBits method in class Double, and then writes that long value to the underlying output stream as an 8-byte quantity, high byte first.

you write 8 bytes that may not be assigned to any alphanumeric character. Then you read it a line as a String (characters up to the next 'new line' char).
In this case, the 'new line' char can be anywhere, or nowhere (depending on the result).

8 bytes in file means almost 4 chars, very likely, no one is a "visible character".

Try to read a `byte[8]` from the InputStream (not from a Buffered one), and then put those 8 bytes into `DoubleBuffer`, then you can get the double value represented by those bytes and writen to the file before.